# How do i clear the OSMdroid cache

Tags: java, android, caching, osmdroid

I loaded the same tiles (Mapbox) into OSmdroid, but know when i modify it on the web, it changes in my app, but the former map still remaines in the cache, and is replace by the new map little by little.

I want to know how to delete the cache, programmatically, so it can load the tiles normally.

I've got the code to load it right here :

```
private void loadMap() {
    String html = "http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/myUsername.map-f1rhoycw/";
    String name = "500x300";
    XYTileSource freemap = new XYTileSource(name, null, 0, 16, 256, ".png", html);
    map.setTileSource(freemap);
    mapController = map.getController();

    mapController.setZoom(16);

    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

}
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the same issue and I think that I should delete cache folder, but maybe there is better solution?

Comment: No i didn't find anything, but nevermind, i returned to the good old Google Maps.

Comment: My problem was with dynamically switching two maps, but I've discovered that name specifies the folder where the maps are kept, so I've just used two different names.
The only way of solving your case (I know you've said nevermind :)) is to make app checke what is the current version of maps and change their's name accordingly.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909807/8313316

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mMapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache()
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I changed the tile soruce and did this, but it still displayed the old cached tiles in the areas of the map I had viewed.