# How to clear cache in osmdroid?

Tags: android, caching, osmdroid

The code below is not working.

```java
mapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my question. After going through the source in order to find out why the cache is not cleared after executing

```java
mapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();
```

i found two functions in:

```
org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.SqlTileWriter.java
```

Functions:

```java
/* purges and deletes everything from the cache database */
 public boolean purgeCache(){..}
```

and

```java
/* purges and deletes all tiles from the given tile source name from the cache database */
 public boolean purgeCache(String mTileSourceName){..}
```

Example to delete cache for specific tile source:

```java
SqlTileWriter sqlTileWriter = new SqlTileWriter();
boolean isCleared = sqlTileWriter.purgeCache(mapView.getTileProvider().getTileSource().name());
```